# summing the first and last elements of list

Tags: python, list

I'd like to sum the first element and last elements of a list, and then exclude those two numbers and repeat that process again until there is only one element in the list. Like this:

```
[5,4,3,2,1,6]
[11,5,5]
[16,5]
[21]
```

I used some methods but didn't work.
I am just a computer science student starting to python so help me out please guys.
Thank you.

Comment: Please, take [tour], check [ask] and [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4046632). Show what have you tried and how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main logic of this answer is revolve around `len of last list print`. Lets break it in few points :

**LOGIC :**
**1.** Basically we need sum of `first-ith` and `last-ith` value for that we used this code:

```
l_u[-1][i] + l_u[-1][-i - 1]
```

**2.** Above point is only valid when `lenght of last append list` is `even` for `odd-length` we have to append this only at even poistion :

```
l_u[-1][i]
```

**3.** Among above two statement which is going to `true` this is done by this condition:

```
len(l_u[-1])%2 != 0 and i%2 != 0
```

**CODE :**

```
l = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6]
l_u = [l]

condn = True
j = 0

while condn:
    l_u.append([
        l_u[-1][i] if len(l_u[-1]) % 2 != 0 and i % 2 != 0 else l_u[-1][i] +
        l_u[-1][-i - 1] for i in range(
            len(l_u[-1]) // 2 if len(l_u[-1]) % 2 == 0 else len(l_u[-1]) // 2 +
            1)
    ])

    if len(l_u[-1]) <= 1:
        break

print(l_u)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6], [11, 5, 5], [16, 5], [21]]
```